# will ```yum update && yum upgrade``` upgrade my centOS 7.1 minimal

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, upgrade

am managing a production server for a network forensic tool that is running currently on centos 7.1 minimal which is the requirement. I am avoiding any upgrades on the version, will the  `yum update && yum upgrade` command perform an upgrade on my current version? , if yes how can I avoid this, because I need to install necessary packages on my server

Comment: Those commands will upgrade the version. You can exclude it but the kernel and all of the other packages would still be upgraded. If you want to keep it at that version with everything in place from that version, then you are running a system with known security flaws. If that's necessary for the tool to run, then the system shouldn't even be connected to the network to run `yum` anyway.

Comment: @NasirRiley is there any command you can help or recommend that won't run an upgrade on the version, will be grateful

Comment: You can add the centos-release to the exclude line in `/etc/yum.conf` but it would be useless as the commands would still upgrade the kernel and the other packages and effectively give you a FrankenCentOS.

Comment: What is it with forensic tools demanding obsolete, insecure versions of CentOS?

Comment: compatibility issues am guessing